# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets was not found

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs, msbuild

I am publishing my website to Azure using Visual Studio Online. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I have made no changes to my CloudService file and this starting happening today. Is the file path correct? I am receiving this error message:

d:\a\src\XX\Azure\CloudService1\CloudService1.ccproj (70): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

On the first line of my solution file, here is the version:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

## Visual Studio 2013

VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.30501.0

I have made no changes to this area, so I am unsure what's going on.

Comment: Visual studio version v14.0 is from visual studio 2015. What is format version on the first line inside your sln file?

Comment: You should pass the property VisualStudioVersion see http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx

Comment: Hi, I opened CloudService1.csproj. I changed the CloudExtensionsDir code to:  <CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\</CloudExtensionsDir>

Comment: Probably Azure sdk version issue. Installing correct version of sdk should fix it.